# Hi , i am building an indicator with cum function but facing problem

Tags: pine-script

I am building an indicator which cumulates volume for 200 days (may need an input function for 200 days).

below is my code :

```
//@version=4
study("coineavg", overlay=true)

PriceDis = (close-(high+low)/2) * (close-(high+low)/2)

NewVol = PriceDis * volume

TotalNewVol = cum(NewVol)

WeightedVol = NewVol / TotalNewVol

WeightedPrice = close * WeightedVol

plot(WeightedPrice)
```

the problem is : the output value is wrong and i think the problem is the line of "TotalNewVol = cum(NewVol)"

Please help me and explain a bit how to use cum function and what is the difference from for loop or sum function

thanks so much !!!!!

Comment: "the output value is wrong" how? What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Also, if you don't know how `cum()` works, why do you use it for? What do you expect it to return?

Comment: For cum() , I know it can cumulate data. For example , I have 3 days volume. cum() could help me sum up the volume of the 1st day , the 2nd day and the 3rd day. And about my indicator , it's similar to VWAP. 200 days VWAP = Price * (volume/total volume). I wanna calculate MyIndicator for 200 days = Price * (NewVolume / Total New Volume). And the Total New Volume needs to be cumulated for 200 days. So , my indicator doesn't cumulate for 200 days and I am not sure if cum(NewVol) is right as well , thanks man !!!!